# I'm lying about being a RandomAccessIterator—does it matter?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

I wrote a RandIt class (code below) that acts like an iterator, but returns random integers whenever dereferenced. The main use case is to initialize a vector with random data, as in

```
std::vector<int> v(RandIt<0,99>{}, RandIt<0,99>{50});
```

to generate 50 numbers between 0 and 99.

The typedef `RandIt::iterator_category` is `std::random_access_iterator_tag`, because

- it needs to be at least a ForwardIterator for the vector constructor to allocate the right amount of space to build into, with `std::distance`. Otherwise `emplace_back` is used, with reallocation and copying.
- it needs to be RandomAccessIterator for `std::distance` to be constant time, instead of incrementing and testing in a loop.

However, this is a lie, since dereferencing a RandIt returns an `int` by value, and ForwardIterators and better are all required to return a reference to an object in memory.

(It may also be a lie because of failing ForwardIterator's "multipass guarantee": going over the sequence again will give different results. But [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator#Multipass_guarantee) gives the "formal" version

> the expression `(void)++It(a), *a` is equivalent to the expression `*a`

which seems to be true, for certain values of "equivalent".)

So I am definitely breaking the rules by claiming to be something I'm not. Nonetheless, it seems to work.

**Is this going to bite me? What are the potential effects of lying about this?**

---

```
#include <random>
#include <iterator>

template <int min, int max>
struct RandIt {
    typedef int difference_type;
    typedef int value_type;
    typedef const int* pointer;
    typedef const int& reference;
    typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category; // this is a lie

    static std::knuth_b rng;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> idist;
    int i;

    explicit RandIt(int i = 0) : i{i} {}

    int operator*() const {return idist(rng);}
    int operator[](int) const {return idist(rng);}

    RandIt& operator++() {++i; return *this;}
    RandIt  operator++(int) {return RandIt{i++};}
    RandIt& operator--() {--i; return *this;}
    RandIt  operator--(int) {return RandIt{i--};}
    RandIt& operator+=(int k) {i += k; return *this;}
    RandIt& operator-=(int k) {i -= k; return *this;}
    RandIt  operator+ (int k) const {return RandIt{i+k};}
    RandIt  operator- (int k) const {return RandIt{i-k};}
    friend RandIt operator+(int k, RandIt a) {return RandIt{k + a.i};}

    friend int  operator- (RandIt a, RandIt b) {return a.i - b.i;}
    friend bool operator==(RandIt a, RandIt b) {return a.i == b.i;}
    friend bool operator!=(RandIt a, RandIt b) {return a.i != b.i;}
    friend bool operator<=(RandIt a, RandIt b) {return a.i <= b.i;}
    friend bool operator< (RandIt a, RandIt b) {return a.i < b.i;}
    friend bool operator>=(RandIt a, RandIt b) {return a.i >= b.i;}
    friend bool operator> (RandIt a, RandIt b) {return a.i > b.i;}
};


template <int min, int max>
std::knuth_b RandIt<min, max>::rng{std::random_device{}()};
// On some platforms (mingw), random_device is deterministic, so rng 
// will always produce the same values.

template <int min, int max>
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> RandIt<min, max>::idist{min, max};
```

[See it on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c95306383a57542).

Comment: It's not even a valid input iterator since `*it` is supposed to return `reference`.

Comment: @T.C.: So should I just `typedef int reference;` or will that make everything worse? (Assigning `*it` to a `const int&` _does_ work here, in general, due to temporary lifetime extension.)

Comment: `std::sort` takes a RandomAccessIterator. I cannot imagine any particular implementation of it reacting well to this class claiming to be a RandomAccessIterator.

Comment: @jaggedSpire: Well, it's not a _mutable_ RandomAccessIterator, so it's not valid for `std::sort` anyway.

Comment: _"The main use case is to initialize a vector with random data"_ So we need to assume you're deliberately avoiding the tenths of ways to accomplish that sanely.

Comment: @black: This is the only sure way to do it without unnecessary zero-initialization or reallocating/copying. You can do pretty well with `std::vector<int> v; v.reserve(50); std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), n, rndint(0, 99));` where `rndint` is an appropriate functor. But (a) there may be an unnecessary allocation when declaring `v` (b) this is excessively verbose and ugly. (If by "tenths of ways" you mean that all other approaches are only fractional, and taken all together don't add up to doing it sanely—then we agree. ;-)

Comment: "Excessively verbose and ugly" is solved by putting that into a factory function template. I don't think you justified the undefined hack in your answer.